# Why is c++ multithreaded program slower on two machines with the same processor?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, performance-testing

I wrote a simple c++ multithreaded program to do several fft iterations, the objective is to get a mflops score of the machine.

I have two (virtual) machines, both running ubuntu:

machine 1: 2core 8gb ram

machine 2: 2core 16gb ram

both machines have the exact same characteristics except the memory, however the avg. results are:

machine 1: 530mflops

machine 2: 850mflops

[image: mflops result]

here is the top command showing the resources consumed:

[image: top results]

the one on the left is the 8gb machine and on the right the 16gb machine.

memory swapping shouldn't be an issue, each thread consumes 1mb memory, any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: What else is running on the machines?

Comment: It's just mflops, not mflops/s. The "ps" is "per second"

Comment: @Bathsheba nothing they're dedicated for testing this program alone

Comment: Really? What about the OS? Point I'm trying to make is that these kind of tests are difficult to set up.

Comment: Do you run those two VMs on the same physical host?

Comment: @Bathsheba both are running ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, yep yep I understand but already checked cpus and memory they're exactly the same except for the amount

Comment: @RemusRusanu not really sure at the moment, I'll try to find out, these are machines the client provided.

Comment: And are there any other VMs running on same physical hosts at the moment of the tests ?

Comment: http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html

Comment: @RemusRusanu here is the cpu stats: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gacynjhrd61s9ek/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-04%20at%209.39.30%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: And you're sure you run the same binaries, did not do a trivial mistake like running [`-O0` vs. `-O3`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: Did you try to decrease the memory to have exactly the same setting on both machines? Did you repeat the test several times? Do you always get the same results?

Comment: @dirac3000 I haven't tested decreasing the memory, yes test was repeated several times with an array of values, from varying threads to test duration.

Comment: You have 5 and 4 users logged in. Are you sure, they don't cause any load? Also: for identical systems doing nothing, its strange that the slower machine has a much higher average load of 0.7 vs. 0.3.

Comment: If I was you I would try to decrease the memory. Being the only variable you know is different, you should expect the systems to behave the same way. Otherwise some other setting might be interfering with your test.

Comment: After a lot of profiling and testing I cannot find a cause for the problem, client provided another instances in amazon and the behaviour was much predictable and stable throwing correct results, I can only point my finger at the cloud service provider.

If the client wishes for me to keep looking into the matter then I will try to lower the ram of both machines, until then I thank you all for the suggestions you gave.